# Can we change the order of fermionic ladder (creation and annihilation) operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators

For example, can you change
$aa^{\dagger}$ to $a^{\dagger}a$
and there is no consequential sign changes or additional terms? This is for fermions. Same question applies to swapping the order either way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *can* happen, in which case the fermions are known as Majorana fermions. However, it does not usually happen and therefore the fermion annihilator can be written as $a=|0\rangle\langle1|$ and the identity operator as $1=|0\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle1|,$ from which you may see the usual anticommutation relation that
$$1=aa^\dagger + a^\dagger a.$$
So you can anticommute them by picking up some extra constant terms. It also helps to manipulate them to see that $aa=0$, annihilating the vacuum is zero, so if you have a big chain of creation and annihilation operators often commutation can create a case where you have $a_ka_{k'}$ and you now know that $k\ne k'.$

Answer (score 1):

Fermions creation and annhilation operators obey an anti-commutation relationship such as

\begin{equation}
\{b^r_\vec{p},{b^s_{\vec{q}}}^\dagger\}\equiv b^r_{\vec{p}} {b^s_{\vec{q}}}^\dagger+{b^s_{\vec{q}}}^\dagger b^r_{\vec{p}} = (2\pi)^3\delta^{rs} \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})
\end{equation}

So... no, you can't just switch the order, you pick up a minus sign as well as the delta function.

Source: David Tong QFT lecture notes, Section 5.2, https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html